# How to allow two different installation of executables from the same source code in Windows machine

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I'm currently working on two `ReactJs` `Electron` project using the same source code. In case my statement are confusing, I got `Product A` and `Product B` on the same source code but the differences between both are the logo and configurations.

When I use `electron-builder` to generate the executable file, it indeed come out as two different executable and when I install both executable, it did appear as two different application. But the problem is that, when I opened both application, it overwrite the previous installation.

I did assume changing the `setAppUserModelId` on my `electron.js` and `appId`, `name` and others in `package.json` will trick Windows into thinking that both project are different but ended up it doesn't.

```
//electron.js

app.on("ready", () => {
  createWindow();
  if (process.platform === "win32") {
    app.setAppUserModelId("com.product.a"); //similar thing goes to Product B
  }
});
```

```
//package.json

"build": {
   "appId": "com.product.a",
   "win": {
     "target": "NSIS",
     "icon": "build/logo.ico"
   }
},
```

**Problem:**

I install `productA.exe` first then install `productB.exe`, two application did show up as separate application, but when I launch `Product A`, it shows `Product B` and when I launch `Product B` it shows `Product B` (which doesn't wrong).

**Expectation:**

What I trying to achieve here is that, when I install `productA.exe` it shows `Product A` and when I install `productB.exe` it shows `Product B`.

**Question:**

Did I configure my project wrongly or did I missed out something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon restructuring the package.json by moving appId inside "build" to outside, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

you should modify package.json "name": "ProductA" or "ProductB"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a good solution to this problem. Changing the location of appId doesn't work.

Comment: If you have more information about your question, please edit your original post and avoid making a new comment.